# How to select multiple dropdown and submit them to the databse using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a roster program. I select a name of an employee, I select the dates and the sites he will be working on and the shifts if its day or night for each date and submit it to mysql. I managed to implement multidate selection but now I want to select multiple sites and shift type corresponding to the dates. I don't want them to mix up when they are submitted to the database.

Example

```
Name : James Date: 2020-12-16 Shift: Night Sitename : KFC 
Name : James Date: 2020-12-17 Shift: Day Sitename   : McDonald's  
Name : James Date: 2020-12-28 Shift: Night Sitename : New Your City park 
Name : James Date: 2020-12-30 Shift: Day Sitename   : Airport
```

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Roster  </title>
    <meta charst="utf-8">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Isolated Version of Bootstrap, not needed if your site already uses Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
    
    
    <!-- JS & CSS library of MultiSelect plugin 2020-12-15 -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/multiselect.css" />  
    
    <!-- Jquery Multiselect Musa -->
    
    <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
    
    <!-- jQuery-- multiselect -- >
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="start_time"]'); //our date input has the name "start_time"
     var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
          var options={
          multidate:true,
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: false,
          };
          date_input.datepicker(options);
        });
    </script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#sitenames').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#btnget').click(function() {
    //alert($('#sitenames').val());
    })
    });
    </script>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Form code begins -->
     <form method="post" action="md.php">
     <div id="peoplenames" style="padding:10px">
    <select name="personname" id ="personname">
    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
    <option value="Gupta">Gupta</option>
    <option value="Messi">Messi</option>
    <option value="Ronaldo">Ronaldo</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
     
      <div class="bootstrap-iso">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" >
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        
          <div class="form-group" > <!-- Date input -->
            <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="start_time" name="start_time" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text" />
          </div>
      </div>
          </div>
      </div>
          </div>
          
          
       <div id="divshift" style="padding:50px">
    <select name="shifttype[]" id ="shifttype" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="">Select day or Night</option>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Night">Night</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>   
       
       
       
          
    
    <div style="padding:100px">
    <select name="sitenames[]" id ="sitenames" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="bp">BP</option>
    <option value="shell">Shell</option>
    <option value="caltex">Caltex</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group" style="padding:150px" > <!-- Submit button -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary " name="btnroster" type="submit">post</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Form code ends --> 
    <?php
    
    // php codes 
    $start_time1 =(isset($_POST['start_time']))? trim ($_POST['start_time']):'';
    $empid =(isset($_POST['personname']))? trim ($_POST['personname']):'';
    
    
      
     if(isset($_POST['btnroster'])){ // button starts here 
         
    
    $start_time2 = explode(",",$start_time1);
     foreach ($_POST['shifttype'] as $shifttype){ // shifts day anad night 
     foreach ($_POST['sitenames'] as $siteid){ // site  
    foreach($start_time2 as $start_time){  // dates foreach 
    
    $query ='INSERT INTO tbljobassignment(empid, siteid,shifttype,start_time)
    VALUES
    (:empid, :siteid,:shifttype,:start_time)';
    $insert=$con->prepare($query);
    $insert->execute(array(
    ':empid'=>$empid,
    ':siteid'=>$siteid,
    ':shifttype'=>$shifttype,
    ':start_time'=>$start_time));
    } // site ide loop 
    
    } // End of foreach loop 
      
      
      
      
      
      } // First foreach ends here 
      } // second foreach eands here 
      } // 
      }//button ends here 
      
         ?>
    
     
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Have you tried narrowing down the problem? Seems like most of the code you posted is irrelevant to the question. It also seems like your query shouldn't be working at all as you pass 4 parameters for a query that has 6 placeholders.